# Batch Watermark images using GD

Tags: php, gd, watermark

I have been looking high and low around the internet for a code to Batch watermark images in a  folder. I want to add a transparent .png watermark to them all but the only scripts i can find are for one(1) single file and not all in one directory.

I tried to search google but there was no luck at all as i mentioned in my text above,

Comment: So take the code that does it for one image and wrap it with some code to process all image files in a folder

Comment: I tried it with the following code but cant get to watermark all the images in my folder :/

http://runnable.com/UnF5hbIOBM91AAAb/how-to-add-watermark-to-an-image-with-gd-library-for-php

Answer (score 0):

i made this code, it paste the watermark just in midle of the other image.
it work fine in browser, but it doesn't in comand line
i hope it work for you.

```
$dir_to_img='Wallpapers_Azul';
$watermark = "angel.png";
$dir_to_new_image='watered';

    if(is_dir($dir_to_img)){
        if($dir = opendir($dir_to_img)){
            while(($archivo = readdir($dir)) !== false){
                if($archivo != '.' && $archivo != '..' && $archivo != '.htaccess'){
                    if(substr($archivo, -4) == '.jpg' || substr($archivo, -4) == '.JPG') //only jpg files

            $im = imagecreatefrompng($watermark);
            $im2 = imagecreatefromjpeg($dir_to_img."/".$archivo);

                imagecopy($im2, $im, (imagesx($im2)/2)-(imagesx($im)/2), (imagesy($im2)/2)-(imagesy($im)/2), 0, 0, imagesx($im), imagesy($im));

        if(!is_dir($dir_to_new_image)){   //save to another dir
            mkdir($dir_to_new_image, 0777, true);
        }

        imagejpeg($im2,"$dir_to_new_image/$archivo",90);
        imagedestroy($im);
        imagedestroy($im2);
                }
            }
        closedir($dir);
        }
    }
```

result:

original

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, i just tried it out but i get the following errors! :/

Notice: Undefined variable: image_in_folder in /home/gallery/test/test.php on line 20

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/gallery/test/test.php on line 20

Comment: @user2406918 check the code now, i could run it from command (windows 8)

Answer (score 0):

Use this codes working with [TopiLib](http://topilib.hadiabdikhojasteh.ir/) :

```
<?php 
function renderToImage($inputImagePath, $watermarkImagePath)
{
require './topi.lib.min';
$panel = new \TopiLib\TopiPanel('png transparent', 9, 0, 0, 0);
$panel->createFromPNG($inputImagePath);
$img = new \TopiLib\TopiImage($watermarkImagePath, 'transparent png');
$img->position = 'left-bottom';      //You can use 'fill', 'fit', 'stretch', 'tile', 'center', 'right', 'right-top', 'right-bottom', 'left', 'left-top', 'left-bottom'.
//Or you can change startX and startY properties
//For text watermark use TopiText object
$panel->addImage($img);    
$panel->renderToImage($inputImagePath . "Edited." . pathinfo($inputImagePath, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
}
?>
```